# How Would I Start With Prolog?

Tags: windows, prolog

If I wanted to start learning Prolog on Windows, is there any package that would integrate Prolog into Visual Studio 2010?  That is, a compiler and templates and so forth for working with Prolog on Windows?

Assuming there is no flavor of Prolog targeting the .Net platform, is there a GCC Prolog compiler for Windows?

Comment: I think this is a quite extensive list of Prolog implementations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations

Comment: Thanks @usoban.  You should post this as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: The .net-implementations of Prolog were toys/experiments that aren't updated any more. You will probably want to get [SWI Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org). And I don't know any Visual Studio integration for prolog, likely due to the lack of anyone using prolog. You can install and use the [SWI Prolog Editor](http://lakk.bildung.hessen.de/netzwerk/faecher/informatik/swiprolog/indexe.html), however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using Google for two seconds, I found the [Prolog.NET](http://prolog.hodroj.net) project. Have a look at that. There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053425/prolog-compiler-for-net) question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) that points to this project.

Comment: You know @Bernard I'm not sure that sarcastic remarks are particularly helpful or necessary. I googled the Prolog.Net project myself before I posted my question but I was hoping that possibly people with more experience might give me a bit more information than a simple pointer to projects. Perhaps I should have mentioned that I had already googled and found it so my question would have been a bit clearer. You might reference birryree's comment above--that's more what I was looking for.

Comment: Next time you should be more clear. We get a lot of people on here that don't bother doing any research of their own and are just looking for a quick answer. If you have done some searching of your own, definitely specify that in your question to set yourself apart from others that do not.

Comment: Apologies--you're right--I should have specified that in my question. It would have saved everyone a bit of trouble.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: If you have already done research on the question, it's a good idea to post what you have found and why it does not satisfy your question. It could also prompt more detailed answers. Otherwise, people will assume you're lazy.

Answer (score 3):

There's an excellent Prolog environment for windows. It's called [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) on [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). I decided to stop swimming upstream when I started learning Erlang and installed Ubuntu. It's been a pleasant journey of rediscovery for me. Linux has come a long way to simplify the process of getting up and running.

I'm assuming you're going through the 7 languages in 7 weeks. While you're at it spend the time to get comfortable with Linux and Virtualization. Both can become good friends.

Comment: BTW if you **are** working through Seven languages maybe we can study together. I jumped straight to erlang (and bought the full Programming Erlang book because I'm smitten by it).

Comment: I played with Erlang a little but I guess because I didn't have a Prolog background the syntax really annoyed me.